# Optimizing code for range selection

Tags: c#, arrays

Given an array and two more arrays i need to find the range of elements in the first array

For e.g. MainArray={2,4,6,5,8,9}, range1={4,5,6}, range2={6,9,8}

for First-Iteration i have to select elements in MainArray in range [4,6] ->[4,6,5] --[3] is the output

for second-Iteration i have to select elements in MainArray in range [5,9] ->[5,8,9]--[3] is the output

for third-Iteration i have to select elements in MainArray in range [6,8] ->[6,8]--[2] is the output

array returned [3,3,2]

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var rng = new Random();

        var result = processFunc(Enumerable.Range(0, 5000000).OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).ToArray(),
            Enumerable.Range(0, 20000).OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).Take(200).ToArray(),
            Enumerable.Range(0, 20000).OrderBy(x => rng.Next()).Take(200).ToArray());
    }
    public static int[] processFunc(int[] scores,int[] l,int[] r)
    {
        IList<int> output = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < l.Length; i++)
        {
            var bestMatch = scores.Where(x => x >= l[i] && x <= r[i]);
            output.Add(bestMatch.Count());
        }

        return output.ToArray();
    }
```

The code runs fine when numbers are small but once they >50,000 the program becomes slow. How can I optimize this solution ?

Comment: `for First-Iteration i have to select elements in MainArray in range [4,6] ->[4,6,5] --[3] is the output` Why is 3 the output?

Comment: @mjwills number of elements in the array

Comment: Are you sure you've chosen the best way to accomplish your task? What, at a slightly higher level, are you trying to do?

Comment: What if Range1 and Range2 are different lengths, or if one of them is null or empty?

Comment: Range1 and Range2 will be same length. I want to know if this is the best way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `l` and `r` have the same length, consider this approach:

```
public static int[] processFunc(int[] scores, int[] l, int[] r)
{
    var min = Math.Min(l.Min(z => z), r.Min(z => z));
    var max = Math.Max(l.Max(z => z), r.Max(z => z));

    var grouped = scores.Where(z => z >= min && z <= max).GroupBy(z => z).Select(val => Tuple.Create(val.Key, val.Count())).OrderBy(z => z.Item1).ToList();

    return l.Zip(r, (left, right) =>
    {
        var matching = grouped.Where(z => z.Item1 >= left).TakeWhile(z => z.Item1 <= right);
        return matching.Sum(z => z.Item2);
    }).ToArray();
}
```

`min` and `max` are used to ignore irrelevant (too large or too small) numbers. `grouped` is used to pre-calculate the counts and put them in order. `Zip` is used to line up the `l` and `r` values and sum the counts together.

*This solution is roughly 2-3 times faster on my machine than the original code (and most of the remaining time being spent is actually setting up the parameters, rather than in the function itself).*

Comment: Can you try with `var result = processFunc(new int[] {4,8,7 },
                new int[] { 2,4},
               new int[] { 8,4});` I am getting keyNotFound error

Comment: When I run your code against `var result = processFunc(new int[] {4,8,7 }, new int[] { 2,4}, new int[] { 8,4});` the output is `{2,1}` that means when we take [2,8] as range we get 2 elements which is wrong because in the range of [2,8] there are  3 elements [4,8,7]

Comment: they must be between two values and they can also be that two values..Does that make sense ?..BTW fantastic solution